# CIFAR-10 Meaningless Normalization Values

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I tried to build a neural network for a CIFAR-10 database. I used Pytorch Framework.

I have a question about of data loading step.

```
transform_train = T.Compose([
    T.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
    T.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)),
])

trainset = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root=root, train=True, download=True, transform=transform_train)
```

This is a normal step for data loading step. While loading data, I am normalizing values. At the beginning of the my project I found below row.

```
T.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
```

After I searched better transform values, I found this values.

```
T.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))
```

I did not find an explanation why these values were used. Do you have a description of these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can have a look [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/normalization-in-the-mnist-example/457):

The first three values are the means over each channel, while the second triple are the standard deviations.

Comment: `(0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)` are not the standard deviations over each channel in CIFAR10, it seems to be the mean of the standard deviation over each channel *in each image*. Specifically in CIFAR10, it doesn't make much difference but it possibly better to use the regular std calculation instead.